# How to start Jetty using start.jar from the console?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, java, webserver, programming

Having installed `Jetty` through `apt` how do I [start the web server](https://askubuntu.com/q/1252599/847449) to get to a welcome page?

Trying:  `java -jar /usr/share/jetty9/start.jar`

results in:

```
ERROR : Nothing to start, exiting ...

Usage: java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --help  # for more information
```

so far as I can tell, there's no `$JETTY_HOME` configured through Ubuntu -- but perhaps that's not actually how to start the server.

---

Hmm, well, Jetty itself seems to at least be running:

```
   [1][jetty_banner.gif]

                          Welcome to Jetty 9 on Debian

   Jetty is a 100% Java HTTP Server and Servlet Container. This means that
   you do not need to configure and run a seperate web server (like
   Apache) in order to use java, servlets and JSPs to generate dynamic
   content. Jetty is a fully featured web server for static and dynamic
   content. Unlike separate server/container solutions, this means that
   your web server and web application run in the same process, without
   interconnection overheads and complications. Furthermore, as a pure
   java component, Jetty can be simply included in your application for
   demonstration, distribution or deployment. Jetty is available on all
   Java supported platforms.
```

using lynx for above (or gui browser).

But how and where is it configured?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely confident on this. I installed Jetty9 on Ubuntu 18.04 last November from the distro, and struggled mightily to understand what was going on and get it working. A big problem is that the distro diverges in multiple ways from the installation described in the Jetty documentation, and this documentation is not geared to someone who is new to linux. To date I have been unable to find any documentation specific to the distro.

Starting Jetty on my system is a matter of running the following command:

```
systemctl start jetty9
```

You can check the status with the following:

```
systemctl status jetty9
```

On my system, I was able to locate various components by inspecting the systemd configuration file at `/lib/systemd/system/jetty9.service`.

The spot for placing web content is the following:

```
/var/lib/jetty9/webapps
```

There is a `README.TXT` located here with some instructions, and a `root` directory where I have placed my `index.htm`. Presumably you would put your war file here. I haven't tried deploying a war yet.

Getting the host to run securely was also difficult to figure out. But first things first!

Comment: thanks, and, if nothing else -- at least I don't feel quite so silly in asking the q!